# RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set; use RETURN NEXT at or near "QUERY" Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

When I try to compile this function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_proc4(sr_num bigint) 
RETURNS TABLE(sr_number bigint, product_serial_number varchar(35))
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT select sr_number,product_serial_number from temp_table where sr_number=sr_num
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Why do I get this error?

> RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set; use RETURN NEXT at or near "QUERY"

I am using postgres version 8.4.

Answer (score 12):

Aside from a typo (you duplicated `select`, and you didn't terminate the `RETURN` statement with a semicolon), I think you were quite close - just needed to disambiguate the table columns within the query by qualifying them with the table name.  Try this (reformatted hopefully to improve readability):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_proc4(sr_num bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE(sr_number bigint, product_serial_number varchar(35)) AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
      SELECT
        temp_table.sr_number, temp_table.product_serial_number
      from temp_table
      where temp_table.sr_number=sr_num;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Caveat: I only tested this in PG 9.4, so haven't tested it in your version yet (which is no longer supported, I might add).  In case there are issues regarding PLPGSQL implementation between your version and 9.4, you can try this form as an alternative:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_proc4(sr_num bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE(sr_number bigint, product_serial_number varchar(35)) AS $$
  BEGIN
    FOR sr_number, product_serial_number IN
      SELECT
        temp_table.sr_number, temp_table.product_serial_number
      from temp_table
      where temp_table.sr_number=sr_num
    LOOP
      RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

A small sanity check using a table I populated with dummy data:

```
postgres=# select * from temp_table;
 sr_number | product_serial_number
-----------+-----------------------
         1 | product 1
         2 | product 2
         2 | another product 2
(3 rows)

postgres=# select * from test_proc4(1);
 sr_number | product_serial_number
-----------+-----------------------
         1 | product 1
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from test_proc4(2);
 sr_number | product_serial_number
-----------+-----------------------
         2 | product 2
         2 | another product 2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: it gives me the same error `RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set; use RETURN NEXT at or near "QUERY"`

Comment: @user2569524 So it may be that your version of PG has slightly different support/implementation of PLPGSQL (specifically `RETURN QUERY`).  I've added an alternate form to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create `my_func()` which returns `TABLE()` type as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
BEGIN                          -- ↑ ↑ ↑
  RETURN (VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller'));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I got the same error below:

```sql
ERROR:  RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set
LINE 3:   RETURN (VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller'));
                 ^
HINT:  Use RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY.
```

So, I used a [RETURN QUERY statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) as shown below, then I could create `my_func()` without error.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller');
END;  -- ↑ ↑ ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or, I used a [RETURN NEXT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) as shown below, then I could create `my_func()` without error.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE 
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR f_n, l_n IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, `my_func()` returns 2 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
  f_n  |  l_n
-------+--------
 John  | Smith
 David | Miller
(2 rows)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
    my_func
----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
(2 rows)
```